# http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/, How to get chosen data?

Tags: jquery

I have implemented the tag control in Stack OVerflow using the http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ in my local project.

But I have one question, I believe this control can only be used with dropdowns, if thats the case, How can I get list of selected values..
Say suppose I have items as "Quoted", "Non_Quoted", "Yet to Quote", "Removed From Quoting"
and I have selected the "Quoted" and "Yet to Quote" options, if I say dropdown.selectedvalue, it is giving me the "YetToQuote" alone as the value.

But I need all the values that are selected, in the above example bothe Quoted and Yet To Quote.

How can I achieve this. Please help me..

Thanks and appreciate your help.

Can I implement the same for textbox instead of dropdown..with textbox having autocomplete feature of AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

what I'm doing is the following

```
$('#idOfMyDropDown').val();
```

returns (for example)

```
["25", "27"]
```

If this doesn't help, can you please post some code?

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).